# Is there a way to bring up a dialog multiple times using the same object?

Tags: java

Right now, to bring up a dialog I create a new `JDialog` object, then call `dispose` to exit the dialog.

Is there a way I can create a dialog, and call up the same dialog later, using the same object?

The reason I want to do this is so that the values in the text fields will keep their values.

Comment: You can use [`setVisible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible(boolean)) to show and hide it, and don't dispose it.

Comment: If you really need to dispose the JDialog, then you need to persist in some Pojos the "model-data" that is populating the GUI......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JDialog d = new JDialog();
d.setVisible(false);
```

You can also use `this.setVisible(false)` inside the dialog, so it doesn't get destroyed and is usable from the parent class. Also if it has input fields they don't get cleared out.
It's invisible in the windows10 taskbar, don't know about linux.

Answer (score 0):

For dialogs that will be shown/hidden often, I use the singleton pattern. As long as you never need more than one of them, like a "Settings" dialog for example. Make a class that extends JDialog using a [singleton pattern](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).

```
public class SettingsDialog extends JDialog {

    private static SettingsDialog instance = null;

    public static SettingsDialog getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SettingsDialog();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SettingsDialog() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Then when you want to show your dialog (from a button or menu item action listener) as others have mentioned use the setVisible method.

```
SettingsDialog.getInstance().setVisible(true);
```